# Android: Picasso load image failed . how to show error message

Tags: android, image, mediastore, picasso

I am trying to use the picasso library to loading the image store in the mediastore. When I called load(imageview, callback), the picasso call onFail instead of onSuccess. How do I know why the image was not loaded successfully?

Comment: Have a look at this answered question [Picasso Library, Android: Using Error Listener][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052538/picasso-library-android-using-error-listener

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Use builder:

```
    Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
    builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    builder.build().load(URL).into(imageView);
```

**Edit**

For version 2.71828 they have added the exception to the onError callback:

```
        Picasso.get()
            .load("yoururlhere")
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 15):

When you use callback, the picaso will call method onSuccess and onError!

```
File fileImage = new File(mPathImage);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(fileImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.draw_detailed_view_display)
                .error(R.drawable.draw_detailed_view_display)
                .resize(200, 200)
                .into(holder.mImageEvidence, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        holder.mMediaEvidencePb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        holder.mErrorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: how to get the cause of unable to load image in `onError` ?

Comment: Method onError not offers information about the error. It only help you realize there is an error is occurring by show "mErrorImage"

Comment: That's what I know too. Global listener should be used instead.

Answer (score 11):

In case you want to use Picasso with Kotlin and lambda expression it could be as short as this:

```
val picasso = Picasso.Builder(context)
            .listener { _, _, e -> e.printStackTrace() }
            .build()
```

...and then you can load image as usual:

```
picasso.load(url).into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you added internet permission in `Manifest`? With Kevin's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30628461/5675550), Please see the exception log and post the exception here.

Answer (score 0):

```
val picasso = Picasso.Builder(context).listener(
                    object : Picasso.Listener{
                        override fun onImageLoadFailed(picasso: Picasso?, uri: Uri?, exception: Exception?) {
                            exception?.printStackTrace()
                            println("Picasso loading failed : ${exception?.message}")
                        }

                    }
            ).build()
picasso.load(imageUrl).into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to check logs of the Picasso

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have use picasso exception handler. Because if you are to use traditional exception handler(try / catch) it wont catch the actual exception.

var imgURL = Your image url
var imgHolder = Id of your image view

val picasso = Picasso.Builder(this@yourActivity)
            .listener { picasso, uri, exception ->
                //Here your log - Log cat - error
                Log.e("Exception ", exception.stackTraceToString())
            }
            .build()

        picasso.load(imgURL)
            .fit()
            .into(imgHolder)
```