# How to load an image with Picasso from url inside a notification with a callback?

Tags: android, picasso

I would like to load an url that contains an image  to a notification (using picasso library) and as callback i would like to load another image if occurs an error. I found to code for this without callback.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(remoteViews, R.id.image, notificationID, notification);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744344/android-picasso-load-image-failed-how-to-show-error-message

Comment: @Misters I know how to do this inside an activity. This is different because is inside a notification

Comment: I think you are going to need to do this with a Target and handle it manually.

Answer (score 1):

If the code will not run on UI Thread.You can do like following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get();
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) remoteViews.findById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```