# Picasso is not loading images from the external storage

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, universal-image-loader, image-loading

Using Picasso (version 2.5.2) in my android project and trying to load all the images stored in the device in a grid view. Picasso is successfully loading all the images stored in the internal storage but not loading those from the external storage. Also, not getting any errors in the log.

I also checked if the file exists and loaded that successfully in a view using Glide library.

Sample external file path: 
/storage/0403-0201/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180309_120329.jpg

Comment: "not getting any errors in the log" -- AFAIK, there will not be any errors, unless you log them yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25744344/115145

Comment: add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to manifest and handle the request to user for granting permission.

Comment: @RahulKumar, Ohh forgot to mention that the required permission has already been added in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

@CommonsWare, Thanks a lot! I attached Picasso.Listener and got the following stack trace-

```
W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Cannot reset
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.MarkableInputStream.reset(MarkableInputStream.java:99)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:140)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:394)
W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Cannot reset
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.MarkableInputStream.reset(MarkableInputStream.java:99)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.decodeStream(BitmapHunter.java:140)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:217)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:394)
```

I explored this error and found that Picasso 2.5.2 does not display big images and same has been filed as a bug on Picasso github page.

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/907

Solution: Picasso 2.5.x is having the bug but version 2.4.0 is working fine.