# Unable to Load Image with Picasson in Android

Tags: android, picasso

What am I doing wrong with these lines of code trying to load image with Picasso from DrobBox or from Imgur and no success. No error message and this is from an Adapter.

```
  Picasso.with(_context)
            .load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/attendanceapp/guest2.JPG")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_icon)
            .into(holder.attendantHeadshot);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(_context)
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/bfU6EaG.jpg")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_icon)
                .into(holder.attendantHeadshot);
```

Full onBindViewHolder of the RecyclerView.Adapter

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Attendant selectedAttendant = mAttendantList.get(position);

        holder.attendantName.setText(selectedAttendant.getName());
        holder.attendantEmail.setText(selectedAttendant.getEmailAddress());
        Picasso.with(_context)
                .load("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/attendanceapp/guest2.JPG")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_icon)
                .into(holder.attendantHeadshot);


        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(_context.getResources().getColor(R.color.activated_color));
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, try to add error listener to picasso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052538/picasso-library-android-using-error-listener

Comment: Post the adapter code, specifically `getView()` method

Comment: This is a RecyclerView.Adapter, it does not have getview rather it has onBindViewHolder it is loading the placeholder from the device fine, but not the images from the web and I added Internet Permission

Comment: I just tested your code and works fine with Picasso 2.5.2 (I had to delete line `rowView.setBackgroundColor` because don't know what it is)

Comment: Let me try, I was just trying to use that to show alternating row color