# Android Picasso Fragment Pic from URL

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, picasso

I've got problem to load pic from URL do my fragment by Picasso.
When I start app it's start without any errors but pic is not loading.
My app has one MainActivity and three fragments. Below I paste xml of mainlayout and one fragment class. The best for me is this scenario:
when user click button on fragment three(red on image), pic will load from url to imageView which is located on fragment two (yellow on image) above of fragment three.[image: three fragments]
Please help

```
package testowy.com.testowyfragment2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 2015-07-04.
 */
public class Klasadown extends Fragment {
    private klasadownlistener listener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentdown, container, false);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgVV);
        Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Picasso.with(c).load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
                .fit().into(img);

        View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.btnMenu:
                            updateText("Menu");
                            SetImage();
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnKontakt:
                            updateText("Kontakt");
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            };
            Button btnMenu = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
            Button btnKontakt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnKontakt);

            btnKontakt.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            btnMenu.setOnClickListener(clickListener);


            return view;

        }

            public interface klasadownlistener {
                public void onItemSelected(String txt);
            }

            private void updateText(String txt) {
                listener.onItemSelected(txt);
            }

            public void SetImage() {
                ImageView img = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imgVV);
                Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg").into(img);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
                super.onAttach(activity);
                if (activity instanceof klasadownlistener) {
                    listener = (klasadownlistener) activity;
                } else {
                    throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " musi implementowa� interfejs: OverviewFragment.OverviewFragmentActivityListener");
                }
            }

        }


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentup"
            class="testowy.com.testowyfragment2.Klasaup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5">

        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentcenter"
            class="testowy.com.testowyfragment2.Klasacenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">

        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmetdown"
            class="testowy.com.testowyfragment2.Klasadown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_weight="3">

        </fragment>

    </LinearLayout>

package testowy.com.testowyfragment2;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 2015-07-04.
 */
public class Klasacenter extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragmentcenter, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    public void SetText(String txt){
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragmentcenterText);
        view.setText(txt);

    }

    }

package testowy.com.testowyfragment2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Klasadown.klasadownlistener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String txt) {
        Klasacenter fragment = (Klasacenter) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentcenter);

        // sprawdzamy czy fragment istnieje w tej aktywno�ci
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
            // ustawiamy teskt we fragmencie
            fragment.SetText(txt);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgV);
            Picasso.with(this).load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg").fit().into(img);
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to give specific width and height while loading your image?  Like this; "Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(imageView);" In one case, this solved my problem.

Comment: Well, try to remove fit(). If your ImageView height and width params set to "wrap_content", it can make your ImageView invisible.

Comment: Try adding error listener to Picasso and check logcat then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052538/picasso-library-android-using-error-listener

Comment: ImageView has match_parent attr

Comment: when i put empty callback nothing is show at logcat Picasso.with(c).load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
        .resize(50, 50).centerCrop().into(img, new Callback() {
            
            public void onSuccess() {
                
            }

            
            public void onError() {

            }
        });

Comment: It's stupid to say but I forget to add internet permission:) <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 3):

It's stupid to say but I forget to add internet permission:)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

now everything is ok!