# Loading image from google places url to imageview (Android)

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, picasso

I'm trying to load an image from the url that was provided by google place's json response and putting it in an Imageview Layout that's going to show when a marker is clicked. I get no error in run-time or in debug but the image will not display on the Imageview. Is there anything that may cause this?

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/places"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/mapinfoborder">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/place_badge"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/place_badge"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TitlePlaceHolder"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/place_snippet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/place_title"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="SnippetPlaceHolder"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Calling it in my activity:

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_layout, null);
    placeImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.place_badge);
    ...
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(markerPlaces.get(marker.getId())).placeholder(R.drawable.bus)
                        .into(placeImage);
```

Again I get no error so there's really no usable logcat that I can provide.
Any comments/ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17939885/4826114 for error handling

Comment: i think the problem with this one is, you created a new view, but you didn't attach it to the activity-view. Or did you in ...?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I figured out what was going on. It wasn't that the image wasn't loading, it just loads it slow. I'm trying to optimize it which is probably another question on another thread!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_layout, null);
placeImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.place_badge);
...
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
picasso.invalidate(market.getId());
picasso.load(markerPlaces.get(marker.getId()))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.bus)
    .into(placeImage);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Unfortunately, it only displays the placeholder icon