# Image could not be successfully loaded via Picasso and Target

Tags: android, image, bitmap, picasso, target

i´m using Picasso and Target for downloading an image and saving it as a bitmap to pass it into an Object which i use for and RecyclerView.

But when I try to download the image the Target also loads the `onBitmapFailed` or `onPrepareLoad` and the `bitmap`is not successfully received...

where´s the bug in my code? The URL is absolutely correct. when i take the passed URL and paste it in chrome browser the image shows...

***Code***

```
//Get Bitmap
                            targetForBitmap = new Target() {
                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap responseBitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){

                                    bitmap = responseBitmap;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                                    Log.i("prepareLoad", "onPrepereLoad ääääääääääääääääääää ");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                                    Log.i("onBitmapFailed", "onBitmapFailed xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                                }
                            };

                            String url = "Http://" + server_wan + ":" + port_wan + "/" + server_path + "/Produktbilder/" + product_image + ".png";
                            Log.i("url", url);
                            Picasso.with(SpeisekarteActivity.this)
                                    .load(url)
                                    .into(targetForBitmap);
```

targetForBitmap is string instance at beginning of the class (`private Target targetForBitmap`)

Comment: getting any errors?

Comment: I´m not getting the bitmap...it´s loading the two other methods. The bitmap is not shown in recclerview or any other Imageview when i pass for testing...

Maybe important to know is that I´m trying to load many images ... in a loop using this method.

Comment: Internet permissions?

Comment: yes internet is in Manifest

Comment: it seems that is doesn´t enter the onBitmapLoaded method...why?

Comment: Do you check what's the error `onBitmapFailed` listener method? I use Picasso in one of my apps. It does not load some images if they are big.

Comment: yes, i have put them both in an imageView on Screen and there´s showing noting...maybe null or just no image which is passed to the imageView.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the imageview where you want to load the image inside the onBitmapLoaded.
Try using .placeholder(drawable) and .error(drawable) with picasso.Use it after .load function.
    Try checking out here:
    [1]: [Picasso Library, Android: Using Error Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052538/picasso-library-android-using-error-listener)

Comment: for what is the .placeholder(drawable) ?
and .error(drawable) ?

Comment: .placeholder()=it places the dummy image in the imageview while picasso is loading the image. .error()=it places the image in the imageview when picasso encounters error while loading the image