# Picasso nor Glide load images on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, picasso, android-glide

My own application already has internet permissions as I am downloading JSON files onto it. However, Picasso will not load images on the emulator.

I downloaded this Picasso/Glide Dagger example just to make sure that it was not my code that was broken. https://github.com/omaflak/Dagger2-Sample

Whenever I run the example application on the emulator, the images won't load.
However, if I run it on my phone, the images load correctly.

Is there anything in my emulator that I would need to fix to make Picasso or Glide work?

Comment: Is the emulated connected to the internet?

Comment: here you can find how debug Picasso. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052538/picasso-library-android-using-error-listener

Comment: I thought the emulator was connected to the internet as I am sure that I've used Chrome to download APKs for other things. However, it does appear that it is not connected to the internet anymore.

Comment: Turns out that turning it off and on again solved the issue for both applications.

Comment: @MarcoPoloe restarting the emulator worked for me thanks, I wasted an hour on this!